# Why is my dynamic slider no longer working?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, scoping, user-interface, slider

This used to work but I accidentally made some unrecoverable edits and it stopped displaying. It supposed to adjust the background color of the current notebook. Please have a look and see what is wrong.

```
notebookBackgroundGraySlider[] := Module[{x = 1},
  Slider[Dynamic[x]];
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   Background -> Dynamic[RGBColor[x, x, x]]];
  ];
```

Comment: With `1; 2` the `1` won't be displayed either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want this?

```
notebookBackgroundGraySlider[] := DynamicModule[{x = 1},
  Slider[
   Dynamic[x,
    Function[
     x = #;
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> Dynamic[RGBColor[x, x, x]]]
    ]
   ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: If you SetOptions each time then there's no need for `Dynamic` in the option. Regardless of where and when SetOptions is done the Dynamic with a local variable can lead to troubles in a new session. But maybe it does not matter, depends on the context.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit it looks a little different from the way I had it before (when it worked) but who cares this works perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Kuba True. I haven't tested how this persists between sessions or anything, so it will probably need tweaking.